# Mapping yaml array to java object

Tags: java, jackson, snakeyaml

How do i map following yaml data to a java pojo

```
 - messageId: A
   category: A
   severity: A

 - messageId: B
   category: B 
   severity: B
```

the array will contain multiple elements

```
public class Message {
    private String messageID;
    private String category;
    private String severity;
}

public class MessageDefinitionList {
    private ArrayList<Message> msgDefinition;
}
```

Following object-mapper code is not working for me, and returns null

```
MessageDefinitionList msgDefinitionList = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(yaml.load(file)), MessageDefinitionList.class);
```

Comment: You need to provide more code around the actual `readValue` call, as that does not seem to come from snakeyaml. Also the format of your yaml file does not match what you are trying to map it to. You could currently read it into a `List<Message>` and call `MessageDefinitionList#setMsgDefinition`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

msg.yml

```
msgDefinition:
- messageId: A
  category: A
  severity: A
- messageId: B
  category: B
  severity: B
```

POJOs (`lombok` annotated, see how the field names correspond to the ones in YAML)

```
@Data
class Message {
    private String messageId;
    private String category;
    private String severity;
}

@Data
class MessageDefinitionList {
    private List<Message> msgDefinition;
}
```

Mapping with Jackson (you can use `String` or `InputStream` instead of the `File` param as well):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
MessageDefinitionList result = mapper.readValue(new File("src/main/resources/msg.yml"), MessageDefinitionList.class);
```

Jackson YAML maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```